# PHP: nested try-catch does not work within a function

Tags: php

Recently I have started playing around with Exceptions and their handling. Everything seemed to work just fine however I have just hit a brick wall and I'm not sure if there is a solution for my problem or should I remake my code base.

Situation:

I'm executing a small piece of code inside try block and I'm catching all exceptions and simply logging/outputing the errors. I'm trying to execute a function which deletes object from database:

1. It removes the relationships;
2. It removes the object.

What I want to accomplish is: if object removal fails - restore previously removed relationships.

I thought that putting a nested try-catch block inside a function at the place where the final deletion is being performed I would catch an exception and revert the changes, however this does not work inside a function and it simply ignores the try-catch block and goes to the top one.
**HOWEVER**: When I put the same piece of code outside of the function it works just fine and like intended!

Below are two pieces of code - working and not working.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that I purposely made a syntax mistake in "router" DELETE query and it always throws an exception during "$status_r = \sys\database\query($query, $db, $elem_t, $elem);" execution. In the first case it ignores the try-catch block inside the function "delete" and goes to the top try-catch block where function is called.

**NOT WORKING AS INTENDED**

```
try
{
    $db = \sys\database\connect();
    $status = ips\routers\delete($id, $db);
    echo "success";
    \sys\core\log_action("router_delete", "success", "Router '$id' successfully deleted", $db);
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo (sys\errors\is_error($ex->getMessage())) ? sys\errors\parse($ex->getMessage()) : $ex->getMessage();
    \sys\core\log_action("router_delete", "failure", $ex->getMessage(), $db);
}
```

*Code inside delete function:*

```
function delete($id, &$db = false)
{
    // Check if Any Interfaces are set on this router
    if (\ips\interfaces\exists(array("router", $id), $db) !== false)
        throw new \Exception(\sys\errors\exist("Router has active interfaces and cant be removed!"));

    $curr_ip_id = \ips\ips\get(array("router_id", $id), "id", $db);
    if (!\sys\validation\validate("numeric", $curr_ip_id[0]['id']))
        throw new \Exception(\sys\errors\database());

    $status = \ips\ips\revoke($curr_ip_id[0]['id'], NULL, $db);
    if ($status === true)
    {
        // if we get an error we need to revert changes - aka rebind IP to router
        try
        {
            $query = "DELETE FROM routers WHERE i = ?";
            $elem_t = "i";
            $elem = array($id);
            $status_r = \sys\database\query($query, $db, $elem_t, $elem);
            if ($status_r === true)
                return true;
            else
                throw new \Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            $status_rebind = \ips\ips\set_owner(array("id", $curr_ip_id[0]['id']), $id, "router", $db);
            if ($status_rebind === true)
                throw \Exception(\sys\errors\database("Failed Deleting router at the last step. IP reassigned successfully!"));
            else
                throw \Exception(\sys\errors\database("Failed Deleting router at the last step. IP reassigned failed!"));
        }
    }
    else
        throw new \Exception(\sys\errors\database("Failed revoking IP address from router!"));
}
```

**WORKING AS INTENDED**

```
try
{
    $db = \sys\database\connect();

    if (\ips\interfaces\exists(array("router", $id), $db) !== false)
        throw new \Exception(\sys\errors\exist("Router has active interfaces and cant be removed!"));

    $curr_ip_id = \ips\ips\get(array("router_id", $id), "id", $db);
    if (!\sys\validation\validate("numeric", $curr_ip_id[0]['id']))
        throw new \Exception(\sys\errors\database());

    $status = \ips\ips\revoke($curr_ip_id[0]['id'], NULL, $db);
    if ($status === true)
    {
        // if we get an error we need to revert changes - aka rebind IP to router
        try
        {
            $query = "DELETE FROM routers WHERE i = ?";
            $elem_t = "i";
            $elem = array($id);
            $status_r = \sys\database\query($query, $db, $elem_t, $elem);
            if ($status_r === true)
                return true;
            else
                throw new \Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            $status_rebind = \ips\ips\set_owner(array("id", $curr_ip_id[0]['id']), $id, "router", $db);
            if ($status_rebind === true)
                throw new \Exception(\sys\errors\database("Failed Deleting router at the last step. IP reassigned successfully!"));
            else
                throw new \Exception(\sys\errors\database("Failed Deleting router at the last step. IP reassigned failed!"));
        }
    }
    else
        throw new \Exception(\sys\errors\database("Failed revoking IP address from router!"));

}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo (sys\errors\is_error($ex->getMessage())) ? sys\errors\parse($ex->getMessage()) : $ex->getMessage();
    \sys\core\log_action("router_delete", "failure", $ex->getMessage(), $db);
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why try-catch does not work inside the function. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is what transactions are for.

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error? Have you checked that `$status` actually === true in side the function?

Comment: @Prisoner Somehow I haven't thought about it since I'm trying to make this project as versatile as possible, but this would seem like a great idea, even if I had to do a little hardcoding here.

Comment: @superphonic oh I'm very sorry. I forgot to mention that I purposely made a syntax mistake in DELETE query changing "id = ?" to "i = ?" so it would throw an exception for me at query function execution. I'll edit a post in a moment.

Comment: I feel like this is expected behaviour. The function call in the first try block is returning an exception, so it is failing over to the `catch`. Not sure what the solution is though...

Comment: Thank you guys for your input. @Prisoner - I decided to use transactions in this case as it seems like the most viable solution. It works fine. Thanks for reminding me about them as I have not even considered them at that point :)